# How to draw a lune of Hippocrates?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a command that draws a lune of Hippocrates with 4 arguments: The edges A and B and the centers K and L of of the two arcs. My command has 8 arguments although I think it needs to be simplifed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\newcommand{\miniskos}[8]{
\tkzDefPoint(#1){#3}
\tkzDefPoint(#2){#4}
\tkzDefLine[mediator](#3,#4) \tkzGetPoints{a}{b}
\tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=#6](a,b) \tkzGetPoint{#5}
\tkzDefLine[perpendicular=through #5,%
K=#8](#3,#4)\tkzGetPoint{#7}
\tkzDrawArc(#5,#3)(#4)
\tkzDrawArc(#7,#3)(#4)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\miniskos{0,1}{1,2}{A}{B}{K}{.3}{L}{.5}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,K,L)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, I would like to have the option to fill the area between the two arcs, something I don't know how to do with my command.

**EDIT**
A lune is the area between two circular arcs.

Comment: When you list `A, B, K, L` in your question, do you want these to be the points as opposed to `A, B, C, D`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I just renamed the points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your code, you would theoretically need only two points, `A` and `B`. The first solution is about your code, the second is to show the Lune of Hippocrates.

## OP's code

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\newcommand{\mnskos}[3][blue!10]{%
    \tkzDefPoint(#2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(#3){B}
    \tkzDefLine[mediator](A,B) \tkzGetPoints{a}{b}
    \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=.3](a,b) \tkzGetPoint{K}
    \tkzDefLine[perpendicular=through K, K=.5](A,B)\tkzGetPoint{L}
    \begin{scope}
    \tkzDrawArc[fill=#1](K,A)(B)
    \clip (L) rectangle (A-|B);
    \tkzFillCircle[fill=white](L,A)
    \end{scope}
    \tkzDrawArc(L,A)(B)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,K,L)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,K,L)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\mnskos{0,1}{1.5,2.5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

## Lune of Hippocrates

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\newcommand{\mskos}[3][blue!10]{%
    \tkzDefPoint(#2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(#3){B}
    \tkzDefSquare(A,B) \tkzGetSecondPoint{C}
    \tkzDrawAltitude[draw=none](B,C)(A) \tkzGetPoint{O}
    \tkzDrawArc[color=black](O,C)(B)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{D}
    %
    % this
    %\begin{scope}
    %\tkzDefSquare(B,A) \tkzGetPoints{c}{d}
    %\tkzClipPolygon(A,B,d,c)
    %\tkzDrawArc[color=black, #1](D,A)(B)
    %\tkzFillCircle[draw=black,fill=white](O,A)
    %\end{scope}
    %
    % or this
    \tkzCalcLength[cm](O,A) \tkzGetLength{rAB}
    \tkzCalcLength[cm](B,D) \tkzGetLength{rBD}
    \filldraw[black, fill=#1] (A) 
        arc (270:360:\rAB) 
            node[pos=.5, font=\tiny, below right, inner sep=0, outer sep=0pt] {$e$}
        arc (45:-135:\rBD)
            node[pos=.5, font=\tiny, below right, inner sep=0, outer sep=0pt] {$f$}
    ;
    %
    \tkzDrawSegment[style=dashed](C,O)
    \tkzFillPolygon[draw=black,fill=#1](A,B,O)
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black, size=3pt](A,B,C,D,O)
    \tkzLabelPoints[font=\tiny, above](B,C,O)
    \tkzLabelPoints[font=\tiny, below](A,D)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=3]
\tkzClip
\mskos{0,1}{1.5,2.5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah I forgot the color. :P

Comment: It looks simpler but changing the position of the centers will change the shape of the lune.

Comment: @mac Well, it seems that the lune is also not correct (in your code as well, I mean). I'll try to provide another solution. Is regular `Tikz` fine too by the way?

Comment: @mac Well you didn't exactly say what should and shouldn't change in your question. What is a lune and how is Hippocrates' special?

Comment: @mac As cfr said, it'd be helpful to know what can be changed or not in your code. If you were to create multiple of these graphs, what would you be changing? By the way, your code doesn't give [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_of_Hippocrates), are you sure you're calculating this properly? I can supply this last image easily but it's totally different from the one you showed in the question.

Comment: @ Alenanno. The code needs only 4 arguments: the two edges of the arcs and the two centers of them. I admit that my description was not correct: I would like to draw any kind of a lune lot just the specific type of lune like Hippocrates' as show at the ricture. I will add more information about it.

Comment: @ Alenanno. Yes a regular `tikz` solution will be fine.

Comment: My main goal is to find a way to fill this area with color. With `tkz-euclide` or regular `tikz`.

Answer (score 6):

One should always be careful using the `intersections` library as it may not be accurate enough, but given two centres and two radii (and assuming the circles intersect), the following seems to work OK:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,2);
  \begin{scope}[overlay]
  \path [name path=A] (A) circle [radius=3];
  \path [name path=B] (B) circle [radius=3/2];
  \path [name intersections={of=A and B, by={p1,p2}}];
  \end{scope}
  \draw [dashed] (p1) -- (A) -- (p2);
  \draw [dashed] (p1) -- (B) -- (p2);
  \fill [red] let
    \p1=(A),\p2=(B),\p3=(p1),\p4=(p2),
    \n1={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)},
    \n2={atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)}, \n3={atan2(\y4-\y1,\x4-\x1)},
    \n4={veclen(\x3-\x2,\y3-\y2)},
    \n5={atan2(\y3-\y2,\x3-\x2)}, \n6={atan2(\y4-\y2,\x4-\x2)} in
    ($(A)+(\n2:\n1)$) arc (\n2:\n3:\n1) arc(\n6:\n5:\n4) -- cycle;
  \foreach \n in {A, B, p1,p2}
     \fill (\n) circle [radius=.05];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]